# Rooting Exagerate XZPAD700

Tags: rooting

I've just bought a device commercially known as "Zelig Pad", which reports to be "XZPAD700" in settings screen. The device looks made by Hamlet but distributed with Exagerate brand.

It carries Android 4.0.4.

Anybody knows how to root that device?

For sake of curiosity: the device goes in download mode by pressing VOL- + Power. Seeking for something to download into its ROM without bricking it.

Comment: If it is ICS which it is, it will be really difficult...

Comment: Why is it difficult to root ICS ?

Comment: @Simon up to Android 2.3 Gingerbread it was possible to root every device around the world because Android itself carried a bug that could be exploited to install root. ICS fixed that, so another vulnerability must be present to inject root executables. Fortunately, some ICS devices are actually "well open" like Samsung GS3 which offers a dedicated download mode where you can overwrite the firmware. HTC devices should be offering something similar after HTC opened its bootloaders' specifications

Comment: @djechelon : Oh I didnt know I thought all devices were naturally rootable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, the device is already rooted, and it's not documented anywhere.

I don't think that starting it in recovery mode for an odd number of times activates/deactivates root, so I just believe the system carries `su` on its own.

If my unit of measure of "rooting" is ad-freeness then I simply tried to run AdFree from the device. No superuser warning appeared but AdFree not even didn't complain about absence of root, but updated the hosts file!! And the device was completely ad-free.

I also tried to install ES File Manager, and found this magic file: `/system/xbin/su`